# Kotlin and Koin - Conditional dependency injection

Tags: android, performance, kotlin, dependency-injection, koin

I have an interface and it has some implementations as our build is performed.

We use Koin for dependency injection on Android.

Is it possible to define which implementation of the interface will be instantiated according to an environment variable?

For example

- If environment variable is VAR_1, then use as implementation A
- If environment variable is VAR_2, then use such B implementation

Or if you have any suggestions, feel free.

stack

- Kotlin
- Koin
- gradle

Koin Session, but it is not our case.

Comment: Why an environment variable?  You should use gradle, define different targets, and build the correct target.

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like this by using `single { ... }` block,

```kotlin
fun getDuckImpl(target: String): Duck {
  if (target== "LINUX") {
    return LinuxDuckImpl()
  }
  return DefaultDuckImpl()
}

// Inside the `startKoin` block,

module {
  single<Duck> {
    getDuckImpl(System.getenv("SOME_VAR") ?: "")
  }
}
```